# Append a column of descriptive colour strings based on another columns grouping

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph

I have a dataframe of numeric values given to groups as below. I want to plot these on a circular graph using the package `circular`. However, I've run into issues when trying to assign the points colours

```
num = c(2,5,8,10)
name = c("A", "A", "B", "C")
data = data.frame(num,name)
```

Circular will colour the points if presented with a list of colours corresponding to the points, so in this case, that would be:

```
num = c(2,5,8,10)
name = c("A", "A", "B", "C")
col = c("red", "red", "blue", "green")
data = data.frame(num,name,col)
```

On a small dataframe, I can do that manually, but I'm looking to scale this and have it scale colours based on the groupings in the `"name"` column. I also thought about creating a new column manually mapping values in "name" to colours - but again it doesn't really scale well.

Is there any way to pull colour names, of # codes from `scale_colour_manual()` or anything like that ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

Using functions from `dplyr` you can group by `name` and assign an index to each group. Then you can use that index to get a colour value from `scales::hue_pal()`.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(num = c(2,5,8,10),
                   name = c("A", "A", "B", "C"))

data <- data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(n = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(col = scales::hue_pal()(max(n))[n])
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
    num name      n col    
  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>  
1     2 A         1 #F8766D
2     5 A         1 #F8766D
3     8 B         2 #00BA38
4    10 C         3 #619CFF
```